# Register custom Doctrine type in Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

So I have this custom Doctrine type

namespace App\Doctrine\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType;

```
class MyType extends TextType
{
   private $prefix='';

   public function getName()
   {
      return 'my_type';
   }
   public function setPrefix(string $prefix)
   {
      $this->prefix=$prefix;
   }
}
```

I registerd in in the config/packages/doctrine.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            my_type: App\Doctrine\Types\MyType
```

Then in Kernel boot() I'm trying to add some parameters to this type:

```
public function boot() {
   parent::boot();

   $myType=Type::getType('my_type');
   $myType->setPrefix('abc');
}
```

This works perfectly the first time I run the app. The prefix is set for the type and can be used through the whole app. However, the second time I get an Exception:

> Unknown column type "encrypted_text" requested. Any Doctrine
>   type that you use has to be registered with
>   \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the
>   known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this
>   error occurs during database introspection then you might have
>   forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use
>   AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom
>   types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is
>   empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping
>   information.

I then changed boot() to :

```
    public function boot() {
       parent::boot();
       if (!Type::hasType('my_type')) {
           Type::addType('my_type', 'App\Doctrine\Types\MyType');
       }
       $myType=Type::getType('my_type');
       $myType->setPrefix('abc');
   }
```

Now the exception is gone, but the prefix is not set. I know the exceptions gives me information about what to do but I really don't know where to start.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where did you see docs about using the boot() method?  Seems a bit unusual.  Admittedly, I have never seen the setPrefix method before either.  Are you sure it even exists?  Don't see it in the type base class.  Is it one of your methods?  Usually I would expect a compiler pass for this sort of thing.

Comment: I saw it in this questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154380/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-custom-doctrine-type-in-symfony4?rq=1. The method setPrefix exists and I need to pass a prefix to that type from a config file

Comment: I assume you are calling parent::boot() from your boot method?

Comment: yes I did (edited my question)

Comment: Just a complete an utter shot in the dark but surround your code with if ($this->booted === false) { and delete the cache.  Probably won't help.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking in to this. Unfortunatly it does not work. The exception is gone but the prefix is not set anymore. So the type loads OK and I can use it but it does not have the prefix set in boot() since that is not executed (it does the first time the app is run). Clearing the cache only works once...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now I fixed it by removing it from config/packages/doctrine.yml so it's not registered there anymore. In Kernel I can now load it:

```
    public function boot() {
       parent::boot();
       if (!Type::hasType('my_type')) {
           Type::addType('my_type', 'App\Doctrine\Types\MyType');
       }
       $myType = Type::getType('my_type');
       $myType->setPrefix('abc');
   }
```

I still can't really understand why this works before building the cache but not once the cache is build. But well, I can continue now.

If someone has a better answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: Try the bootstrap file took that from the official ramsey uuid doctrine repo doc works for me. Seems weird in there, but that's the recommended way.

https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine#usage

Answer (score -2):

```
#This is may answer!!!


 **IMPORTANTE!! Because in Symfony/PHP (NO Object Oriented Language) don't storaging a state it's need make this form to mapping an ENUM type or any Custom Type similary to ENUM.**
```

For customize and mapping you types as Enum in DB table, you need to have a higher version Symfony >= 4.4 for to use this Bundle. 
Execute it in your project (command prompt)

```
                composer req fresh/doctrine-enum-bundle
```

```
Link  example --> [https://github.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle][1] .
I made do this and it's ok for my app.
```

## 1

```
    So, copy this class from this link 
    [https://github.com/fre5h/DoctrineEnumBundle/blob/master/DBAL/Types/AbstractEnumType.php][1] 
    and storage it in src/DBAL/Types =(IF NOT EXIST, CREATE IT), in your project Symfony => 4.4 o higher version.

    #This is your Base class type.
```

## 2

```
    Create this Table in Your Database (in my case I'm using MySql DB):

    CREATE TABLE players (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        position ENUM('PG', 'SG', 'SF', 'PF', 'C') NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id)
    ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = INNODB
    *****************
```

## 3

```
    Create an Entity class for mapping table  (Players) from your Databae inside your project level directory.

    D:SYMFONY\app\myApp
    php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity --filter="Players"
```

## 4

```
    Create getter and setters for your new Entity:

    D:SYMFONY\app\myApp
    php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

## 5

```
    Generate your CRUD operation for Entty class + frontend.

    D:SYMFONY\app\myApp
    php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App
```

## 6

```
 Create your custom Type class BasketballPositionType 

    <?php
namespace App\DBAL\Types;

use Fresh\DoctrineEnumBundle\DBAL\Types\AbstractEnumType;

final class BasketballPositionType extends AbstractEnumType
{
    public const POINT_GUARD = 'PG';
    public const SHOOTING_GUARD = 'SG';
    public const SMALL_FORWARD = 'SF';
    public const POWER_FORWARD = 'PF';
    public const CENTER = 'C';

    protected static $choices = [
        self::POINT_GUARD => 'Point Guard',
        self::SHOOTING_GUARD => 'Shooting Guard',
        self::SMALL_FORWARD => 'Small Forward',
        self::POWER_FORWARD => 'Power Forward',
        self::CENTER => 'Center'
    ];
}
```

## 7

```
Go inside this path in your Symfony project at 

                      D:SYMFONY\app\myApp\config\packages

and create this class php : doctrime.php.
This class it's necesary for to Register your new Type. 
Can you find more information at link for register new type in synfony 
[https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html][1]

so - REGISTER YOUR NEW TYPE
    Copy this fragment of code end paste in doctrime.php class:

    <?php
    $container->loadFromExtension('doctrine', [
        'dbal' => [
            'mapping_types' => [
                'enum'  => 'string', /////////mapping enum to as stringa
            ],
            'types' => [
                'BasketballPositionType' => App\DBAL\Types\BasketballPositionType::class,
            ],
        ],
    ]);

   So, bindig ENUM type db in String and your new Type is "BasketballPositionType"  !!!!
```

## 8

```
    Now, use your Custom Type in your Entity Class mapping 'Players'.

     <?php

namespace App\Entity;
     ** very important
use App\DBAL\Types\BasketballPositionType;  
use Fresh\DoctrineEnumBundle\Validator\Constraints as DoctrineAssert; 

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Players
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="players")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Players
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="BasketballPositionType", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @DoctrineAssert\Enum(entity="App\DBAL\Types\BasketballPositionType")
     */
    private $position;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPosition(): ?string
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition(string $position): self
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

## RUN

```
         ####################### RUM #######################

             Run you Symfony embeded server 
                                    [  symfony serve ]
             And go later in browser at https://127.0.0.1:8000/players


        I'm use CMDER prompt command because it has Git incorporated. 
        It's very easy!!

      [1]: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html
```

Comment: I can't make head or tail of your formatting: What are you trying to present how?

Comment: Please add all information to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Comment: you put so much effort into this, it's a shame the result is a little hard to follow